# Grid overflowing onto div below

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am creating a personal website to show off my other work and thought it wanted to build the site from scratch myself to learn a skill. I ave finished a "portfolio section" that is using `display: grid` to create multiple tiles to each represent a project I have worked on. It works great and does exactly what I would like it to do. I am now creating a contact section but the portfolio area is overlapping the new contact div I have created and am unsure as to why. Any help is appreciated.

Photo of issue (the lines going through protfolio tiles should say contact and be placed below the portfolio. I set the contact min-height to 800px and only 150-200 is shown as it starts at the beginning of the portfolio section as well.[image: Site visual]

I also have modal containers that are set to hidden until a button is clicked that is below the final contact code but it doesnt seem to be the issue so I did not post.

Code:

```css
// ----------------------Portfolio Tile Styles----------------------//

.portfolio{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(245,245,245); 
}

//Styles for the portfolio buttons
.btn-container{
  margin-top:50px;
  background-color: rgb(245,245,245); 
  text-align: center;
  

}

//Styles to set all portfolio tiles to be initally hidden;
  .photogrammetry, .cv, .dev{
    display: none;
  }
  

.filter-btn{
  padding: 5px 20px;
  margin:10px 5px;
  border: 2px solid #e31b6d;
  color: #e31b6d;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition:transform .3s;
  transition: color .3s;
  transition: background-color .3s;
}

.filter-btn:hover{
  color:white;
  background-color: #e31b6d;
}

.gallery-wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(245,245,245); 
}

// Portfolio Gallery Styles
.gallery{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 7%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0% 5% 2% 5%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(19rem, 1fr));

}

/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
.show {
  display: block;
}

.card{
  overflow: hidden;  
  align-items: center;
  width: auto;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-size: cover;



}


.top-text{
  text-align: center;
  transform:translateY(-100px);
  transition:transform .3s;
}

.card-btn,{
  width:50%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #e31b6d;
  opacity: 1;
  border: 2px solid #e31b6d;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform:translateY(100px);
  transition:transform .3s;
  transition: color .3s;
  transition: background-color .3s;
}



.card:hover{
   .card-btn{
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }

  .top-text{
  transform:translateY(0px);
  }
}

.card-btn:hover{
    color:white;
    background-color: #e31b6d;
  }

//Tile Backgrounds
.AutoFP {
    background: url("../images/portfolioTile/AFP_Tile.png") center no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover;
  }
.fpl-1 {
    background: url(https://media.defense.gov/2013/Jul/16/2000032379/-1/-1/0/130628-F-DQ639-002.JPG) center no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover;
  }

.fpl-2 {
    background: url("../images/portfolioTile/IS_Tile.jpg") center no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover;

  }

.fpl-3 {
  background: url("../images/portfolioTile/Algae_Tile.png") center no-repeat;  
  background-size: cover;
}
.fpl-4 {
  background: url("../images/portfolioTile/AFP_Tile.jpg") center no-repeat;  
  background-size: cover;

}
.fpl-5 {
  background: url("../images/portfolioTile/UCW_Tile.png") center no-repeat;  
  background-size: cover;
}
.fpl-6 {

  background: url("../images/portfolioTile/Portrait_Tile.png") center no-repeat;  
  background-size: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
.fpl-7 {
  background: url("../images/portfolioTile/CamCal_Tile.png") center no-repeat;  
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: white;
}

//Faded Tile Background
.AutoFP:hover{
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.7), rgba(255,255,255,0.7)),url("../images/portfolioTile/AFP_Tile.png") center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.fpl-1:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.7), rgba(255,255,255,0.7)),url(https://media.defense.gov/2013/Jul/16/2000032379/-1/-1/0/130628-F-DQ639-002.JPG) center no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover;
}

.fpl-2:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.7), rgba(255,255,255,0.7)),url("../images/portfolioTile/IS_Tile.jpg") center no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover;
}

.fpl-3:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.7), rgba(255,255,255,0.7)),url("../images/portfolioTile/Algae_Tile.png") center no-repeat;  
  background-size: cover;
} 
.fpl-4:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.7), rgba(255,255,255,0.7)),url("../images/portfolioTile/AFP_Tile.jpg") center no-repeat;  
  background-size: cover;
}
.fpl-5:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.7), rgba(255,255,255,0.7)),url("../images/portfolioTile/UCW_Tile.png") center no-repeat;  
  background-size: cover;
}
.fpl-6:hover {

  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.7), rgba(255,255,255,0.7)),url("../images/portfolioTile/Portrait_Tile.png") center no-repeat;  
  background-size: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
.fpl-7:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.7), rgba(255,255,255,0.7)),url("../images/portfolioTile/CamCal_Tile.png") center no-repeat;  
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
```

```html
<!---------------------- Portfolio Gallery ---------------------->
 <!-- Where the tiles will go shocasing work -->
 <div class="portfolio" id="portfolio">
  <h1>Projects</h1>
  <div class = "btn-container">
   <button class="btn active filter-btn" onclick="filterSelection('all')">All</button>
   <button class="btn filter-btn" onclick="filterSelection('photogrammetry')">Photogrammetry</button>
   <button class="btn filter-btn" onclick="filterSelection('cv')">Computer Vision</button>
   <button class="btn filter-btn" onclick="filterSelection('dev')">Developer</button>

  </div>

  <div class = "gallery-wrapper">
   
   <div class = "gallery">
    <!-- Tile 1 -->
    <div class = "photogrammetry dev filterDiv">
     <div class = "AutoFP card ">
      <div class ="top-text">
       <h3 class = "card-heading">Automated FlightPlanning</h3>
       <span>Electron, Python</span>
      </div>
      <button class="card-btn" id ="AutoFP">Learn More</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Tile 2 -->
    <div class = "dev cv filterDiv">
     <div class = "fpl-1 card ">
      <div class ="top-text">
       <h3 class = "card-heading">Change Detection</h3>
       <span>OpenCV, Python</span>
      </div>
      <button class="card-btn" id ="cd">Learn More</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Tile 3 -->
    <div class = "dev cv filterDiv">
     <div class = "fpl-2 card ">
      <div class ="top-text">
       <h3 class = "card-heading">Image Stitching</h3>
       <span>C++, OpenCV</span>
      </div>
      <button class="card-btn" id ="imgStitch">Learn More</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Tile 4 -->
    <div class = "dev cv filterDiv">
     <div class = "fpl-3 card " >
      <div class ="top-text">
       <h3 class = "card-heading">Algae Detection</h3>
       <span>OpenCV, Python</span>
      </div>
      <button class="card-btn" id ="AlgDec">Learn More</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Tile 5 -->
    <div class = "photogrammetry filterDiv">
     <div class = "fpl-4 card ">
      <div class ="top-text">
       <h3 class = "card-heading">Aerial 3D Model</h3>
       <span>DJIFlightPlanner, MetaShape  </span>
      </div>
      <button class="card-btn" id ="A3DM">Learn More</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Tile 6 -->
    <div class = "dev filterDiv">
     <div class = "fpl-5 card ">
      <div class ="top-text">
       <h3 class = "card-heading">University Course Website</h3>
       <span>HTML, CSS</span>
      </div>
      <button class="card-btn" id ="UCW">Learn More</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Tile 7 -->
    <div class = "photogrammetry filterDiv">
     <div class = "fpl-6 card ">
      <div class ="top-text">
       <h3 class = "card-heading">University Course Website</h3>
       <span>Research Paper</span>
      </div>
      <button class="card-btn" id ="RP">Learn More</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Tile 8 -->
    <div class = "photogrammetry filterDiv">
     <div class = "fpl-7 card ">
      <div class ="top-text">
       <h3 class = "card-heading">Camera Calibration of "Prosumer" drones</h3>
       <span>Journal Article</span>
      </div>
      <button class="card-btn" id ="JA">Learn More</button>
     </div>
    </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 

 <!---------------------- Contact Page ---------------------->
 <div>
  <div class = contact-wrapper>
   <h1>CONTACT</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Try removing `position:absolute` from `.gallery-wrapper`.The browser does not leave space for the height of an absolute div and as such any elements below will come up to the previously non absolute aligned div.....maybe...

Comment: Hero thank you. Had a hunch it had to do with position but have been staring at this for way too long.